# Is there a faster process for converting splines into rigged meshes?

Tags: mesh, scripting, rigging, armature, splines

I wanted to have my character's arms be more akin to that of a cartoonish noodle, so I decided that the best way to accomplish this would be to create a Bezier curve, create a mesh out of that curve by duplicating and converting it, create an armature from the curve's various points, rig the mesh to that armature, and apply a Spline IK constraint. However, I think that there might be an easier way to do it than how I'm currently accomplishing it. Here's my process.

[image: A screenshot of a simple Bezier curve]

Here is a simple Bezier curve. I would then proceed to duplicate the curve three times so that I can use each one for a different purpose.

[image: Three identical curves displayed within the outliner]

I'd then expand the depth of one of the curves to a suitable value ('0.07 m' in this case) and convert it into a mesh.

[image: A bezier curve with a depth of '0.07 m' after it has been converted into a mesh]

Hiding the mesh, I'd move onto another curve, converting it into a mesh while making sure that the depth stayed at a volume of '0 m'. With the mesh being nothing more than a curved line of vertices, I'd then add a Skin modifier. After selecting the modifier's "Create Armature" button and deleting the mesh, I'd have an armature ready for me to utilize.

[image: An armature with a shape identical to the curve]

Before rigging the mesh to the armature, I'd extrude another bone out of the end bone for the sake of accurate deformation.

[image: A bone extruded out of the armature's end bone]

Allowing the mesh to become visible again, I'd select the mesh and then the armature. I'd then parent the mesh to the armature with empty groups (automatic weights give messy results).

[image: The mesh and armature selected, with a menu showing the option to parent the mesh to the armature with empty groups]

Now here comes the part where I want to rip my hair out.

Since automatic weights don't give me the results I want, I'd select the armature, go to the Object Data properties, go to the "Viewport Display" tab, and check "Names". With that out of the way, I'd select the mesh and go into edit mode. I'd then select a ring of vertices and assign it to the vertex group that properly corresponds with the appropriate bone.

[image: Applying a part of the mesh to the appropriate vertex group in edit mode]

And then I'd do it again.

[image: Applying another part of the mesh to the appropriate vertex group in edit mode]

And again, and again, and again, until I eventually run out of vertex groups to assign the model to.

[image: Applying a part of the mesh to the last appropriate vertex group in edit mode]

Now, it's not too big of a deal when I only have 13 bones within this example armature, but if I were to deal with 30 or 50 bones here so that the mesh can look extra smooth while the arm is being deformed by the spline, things suddenly get significantly more tedious to set up than before, especially so if I'm dealing with multiple limbs. After this I'd just add a Spline IK modifier to Bone.11 and add a few fancy hooks to the Bezier curve, but I think you get my problem here.

I don't want to go and apply weights to the various vertex groups in my model so that it responds to every single bone in my armature here. Is there a script/add-on that can do this automatically, or is there a better workflow that would make this sort of thing easier to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

## Skin Modifier

Using the [Skin Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html#skin-modifier) along with a [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) you can do this rather quickly.

The skin modifier has the option to create an armature for you, so convert your curve to mesh first, and use the modifier.

[image]

The spiral in the image below is a very basic example, but you can get the point from it.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting. I'll look into it!

Comment: It works! While it may be an issue if one were to want to imitate the bevel options that the curve geometry allows, it's a quick and simple method that is just what I need for my type of character. Thanks!